# SQL Server 2 Table Sync Recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, synchronization

I'm using triggers to keep two identical tables in a single database in sync.  One is for an internal proprietary system, the other is used to expose a subset of data to the outside world.  I'm not able to use the same table for both.

I need updates, inserts, deletes in either of the tables to be applied to the other.

So far I'm using triggers on both tables instead of a scheduled stored procedure because I wanted immediate updates.  The problem is, an update to table A fires the trigger to update table B, which fires a trigger to update table A, which fires the trigger to table B.... and so on.

What's the best way to stop the recursion?

One way is to check the data first to see if it is different, something like this:

```
        SELECT @cempno = inserted.cempno FROM inserted

        SELECT @count = COUNT(*) 
            FROM jcempy j INNER JOIN zhhjcempy z ON j.cempno = z.cempno AND j.cempno = @cempno
            WHERE (j.ccostcode <> z.ccostcode) 
            OR (j.cimearnreg <> z.cimearnreg)
            OR (j.cimearnot <> z.cimearnot)
            OR (j.cimearndt <> z.cimearndt)
            OR (j.cimearnl1 <> z.cimearnl1)

        IF @count = 1
        BEGIN
            -- Update the record
        END
```

Another way could be to use a third table that holds status flags to show which table first initiated the update, but I've a feeling managing that will be a problem once I have 100 users hammering away at the system.

Any ideas, or comments on what sort of performance penalties the data check will incur?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to have one table actually be an [updatable view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187956.aspx#Anchor_3) pointing to the other?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Unfortunately not, there are third party tools involved here.  Interesting idea though, I didn't think of that.

Comment: You need a redesign that doesn't use triggers. There is an old saying "A man who has one watch knows what time it is, a man who has two is never sure."

Comment: Have you considered using a synonym? You would create a synonym with the name of one of your tables to look at the other one. That way both third party apps can actually use the same table but reference them with different names.

Comment: @SeanLange That's a feature I wasn't aware of.  Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't avoid triggers look at `@@NESTLEVEL` within your trigger.

It should be always the same number. If number is bigger, just do nothing.

Comment: This could work, but how do I know what the @@NESTLEVEL value should be?  I'm getting a consistent one in testing - will this always be the same?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you do direct updates/deletes/inserts it should be "1". In case you use a for these updates a mix of procedures and direct updates tat number can vary. Better get rid of triggers using views or synonyms and have all data in only one table.

Comment: the value was actually 3.  I made it work using TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(), looking at object ID of the opposing trigger.  I understand the comments re not using triggers, but I do not have the option of redesign.  Heard back from one of my vendors and synonyms/updatable views will absolutely not work.  Has to be tables.  Thanks much for the response, appreciated.